# Quickest way of storing a byte array in an array?

Tags: java, arrays

I was wondering what is the quickest way of storing a `byte[]` with an integer index in java without using Maps, TreeMap, ArrayLists etc.

i.e. not like this:

```
private Map<Integer, byte[]> example = new TreeMap()
```

Comment: Why can't you use those things you've listed?

Comment: Just wondering if there is a faster way of doing it.

Comment: It sounds like you're optimizing prematurely.  **Don't**

Comment: nothing I was just wondering the best way to do it as byte[][] looks a little dirty. I was planning to use byte[][].

Comment: If you want to know the fastest way, ask for the fastest way. Not "The fastest way except for {x}", because then if {x} *does* happen to be the fastest way, you're going to get soemthing that doesn't solve your problem.

Comment: @Hugh: if you consider byte[][] to be dirty, what else do you consider dirty? int? long? String? Most of the elements in java are there because they serve a purpose.

Comment: Its a multidimensional array. Like to avoid those :( Personal preference. Think I will settle for it never the less thanks all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
private byte[][] example;
example = new byte[][ARRAYS_COUNT];
example[0] = new byte[10];
example[1] = new byte[20];
...
```

Comment: He wanted to hold them with an **integer** index.

Comment: I don't know how would you use this data structure so can't say for sure is this more efficient or not. For example, if you want to store 3 byte arrays with indexes, say, 0, 1 and 10000000, this is definitely less efficient than TreeMap.

Answer (score 1):

Quickest way would be an `ArrayList<byte[]>`, or you want or not. A `byte[][]` isn't going to work as you can then hold only 2<sup>8</sup>-1 arrays, not 2<sup>32</sup>-1 as you could with an **integer** index which you explicitly mentioned in your question.

Comment: Ah yes ArrayLists, I think ill try a few and see whats quickest. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

How about `byte[][]` and resize as appropriate? Not as good as an `ArrayList` but you banned that...